# Generic object creation method with default data

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I'd like to have two simple calls in a class that would be transformed by other classes. Something like:

```
ObjectCreator.CreateBlank<Human>();
ObjectCreator.CreatePopulated<Human>();
ObjectCreator.CreateBlank<Dog>();
ObjectCreator.CreatePopulated<Dog>();
```

I currently do this:

```
public class ObjectCreator
{
    public static T CreateBlank<T>()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public static T CreatePopulated<T>()
    {
        //Somehow return new object with populated properties
    }
}
```

I am struggling with the populated part. I'd like it to return a "default" object of that type with defined properties. I've tried a few things involving passing in interfaces, but it gets messy fast (I don't expect this to be particularly clean either)

So If I called ObjectCreator.CreatePopulated(), I'd like it to somehow go to a different class where I create a new Anything, and fill it's properties to specific values. It feels like I'm close but missing a piece of the puzzle here.

My end game here is to have the call be as simple / readable as possible.
Any help is appreciated.

**I DO realize it'd probably be easier to simply call a class that creates and populates each object, but this is a learning exercise for me and I'd like to attempt to get this working as generically as possible.**

Comment: You could probably do this with Reflection. You iterate each object property dinamically and then set a default value according to the property type. Say, "123" for strings, 1 for numbers (int/float/double/decimal) and false for booleans.

Comment: The first question that comes to mind is: populated with what? How would you decide how to populate the data in each instance? Your current method doesn't takes any data as parameters.

Comment: @Alejandro     Populated with default data that I define. So ObjectCreator.CreatePopulated<Human>() would bounce down to a class where I actually return a new instance of a Human with my data. The current methods take no parameters for that reason.

Comment: @Blankdud Then a hardcoded solution would suffice. *ivanPfeff* answer below seems good enough for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend doing something like this:

```
public interface IPopulatable
{
    void Populate();
}

public class ObjectCreator
{
    public static T CreateBlank<T>() where T : new ()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public static T CreatePopulated<T>() where T : IPopulatable, new()
    {
        var populatable = new T();
        populatable.Populate();
        return populatable;
    }
}

public class Human : IPopulatable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Populate()
    {
        Name = "Joe";
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you've pretty much nailed what I was looking for. Well written and easy to follow, thanks!